# Unable to load options for image in graphql using custom json

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm developing a website using Gatsby, by referring https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smHhNzM5Uo4

here he suggested to use graphql for displaying images. such that created a Trips.json, where mentioned the image details as below

```
[
{
    "img": "../assets/images/python.jpeg",
    "alt": "Python Tutorial",
    "name": "Python Tutorial",
    "button": "View Site"
},
{
    "img": "../assets/images/graphana.png",
    "alt": "Graphana Tutorial",
    "name": "Graphana Tutorial",
    "button": "View Site"
},
{
    "img": "../assets/images/git.jpg",
    "alt": "Git Tutorial",
    "name": "Git Tutorial",
    "button": "View Site"
},
{
    "img": "../assets/images/linux.jpg",
    "alt": "Linux Tutorial",
    "name": "Linux Tutorial",
    "button": "View Site"
}
```

]

In the graphql, there are no options under img property but for him, many options were displayed to choose public url or fluid.
[image]

Kindly let me know, how can I get all options under img or let me know to choose
alt, button, name, fluid/src

Answer (score 0):

> Kindly let me know, how can I get all options under img or let me know
> to choose alt, button, name, fluid/src

There's a lot to comment here.

First of all, `fluid` and `fixed` `props` are from [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/) (Gatsby version 2 backward) and it's currently deprecated as you can see in their docs:

> ⚠️ This package is now deprecated
>
> The gatsby-image package is now deprecated

The new plugin is [`gatsby-plugin-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image) (Gatsby version 3 onwards) so, depending on your Gatsby version you will need to use one version or another but keeping in mind, that sooner or later you'll need to upgrade to the new version.

That said, in both cases, you need to tell Gatsby where those images are located because, in the build-time, Gatsby uses its transformers and sharps to treat the image and create the proper GraphQL nodes (what you called "`fluid/src`").

This is done using the help of [`gatsby-source-filesystem`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/). In your `gatsby-node.js` add something like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `images`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/images`
}
```

The `name` stands for the `sourceInstanceName` entity so you will be able to filter the nodes in the GraphQL.

If everything runs as it should, you should be able to see the proper nodes in the GraphiQL playground.